# Displaying a list of the actions performed during install using Inno Setup

Tags: inno-setup

In Inno Setup  it displays all activity using a single static text string. How can this be changed into a list box that takes up the space under the progress bar and lists the actions one by one?

The list box should be resizeable with the dialog and essentially update as the progress updates.

Can this be achieved?

Comment: I do not think it's possible. You can frequently monitor changes to `StatusLabel` and copy its contents to a custom list box. But I do not think there's a way to make sure you never miss any update. Though if the changes come so frequently (dozens changes per second), it may actually not be that big problem, that you miss something.

Comment: @MartinPrikryl Ok. Do you think then that it is worth being a feature request instead?

Comment: Yes - go ahead.

Comment: Raised here: http://news.jrsoftware.org/read/article.php?id=107275&group=jrsoftware.innosetup#107275

Comment: So maybe post it as an answer (*"not possible, but requested"*) -- to close the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not possible. So I have requested it here:

http://news.jrsoftware.org/read/article.php?id=107275&group=jrsoftware.innosetup#107275